# Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, branch

I am using VS 2013 to connect to teamProject in TFS.

I have created parent branch and given every security permission to AdminUsers and Developers.

I have created child branch using parent branch. Now child branch inherit the security of the parent branch.

Is there any way to create child branch without inheriting security of parent branch using VS 2013 UI.

Answer (score 1):

It’s  impossible to achieve it. The security of the child branch is inherited from your team project collection automatically when you creat it .

However, you can manually change them .Right click the child branch, choose **Advanced**→**Security**. In the dialog pops up, select the group AdminUsers and Developers. Change the security as which you need.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can turn off the security inheritance after you branch.

Comment: This is not a strong answer.  Please provide some instructions that the OP can follow in order to "turn off the security inheritance after [they] branch".